# Kotlin flows: async/await execution blocking UI

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, android-volley, kotlin-flow

I want to load multiple data from a rest endpoint in asynchronously using kotlin flows and display it in a recycler view. The data is defined as `ServiceDto`, `ProductDto`, `CategoryDto`. ProductDto has a `categoryId` attribute which references to a CategoryDto.

Every DTO should be loaded and displayed asynchronously but CategoryDto has to be done before ProductDto because I need the category name + dependent products and add it to a `mutableListOf<Any>`. The recycler view will then display the category name followed by the dependent products.

Repository implementation for products

```
fun getProducts(networkId: String) = flow {
    request.getAll("network/${networkId}/products", null)
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        .onStart { emit(ApiResult.Loading) }
        .catch { emit(ApiResult.Error(it.message.toString())) }
        .map { ApiResult.Success(it) }
        .also { emitAll(it) }
}
```

This is the implementation for loading ServiceDto

```
private fun loadServices() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        async {
            viewModel.getServices(baseViewModel.profile?.networkId ?: "")
        }.await().onEach { result ->
            when (result) {
                is ApiResult.Loading -> {} // Handle loading
                is ApiResult.Error -> {} // Handle error
                is ApiResult.Success -> createServiceChips(result.data) // Create UI elements
            }
        }.collect()
    }
}
```

This is the implementation for loading products and categories

```
private fun loadCategoriesAndProducts() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val products = async {
            viewModel.getProducts(networkId).shareIn(lifecycleScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), 1 // currently no idea what this means ) // Convert to hotflow to start loading data

        }.await()

        async { viewModel.getCategories(networkId) }.await().onEach { categories->
            when (categories) {
                is ApiResult.Loading -> {} // Handle loading
                is ApiResult.Error -> {} // Handle error

                is ApiResult.Success -> {
                    publishCategoryUI(categories.data)
                    collectProducts(products, categories.data)
                }
            }
        }.collect()
    }
}
```

This is how I collect the products and map category and products to a flat list.

```
private suspend fun collectProducts(products: SharedFlow<ApiResult<List<ProductDto>>>, categories: List<CategoryDto>?) = coroutineScope {
    products.onEach{  productResult ->
        when (productResult) {
            is ApiResult.Success -> {
                val productCategoryList = mutableListOf<Any>()
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                    categories?.forEach { category ->
                        productCategoryList.add(category.name)
                        productResult.data?.filter { product ->
                            product.categoryId == category.id
                        }.let {
                            productCategoryList.addAll(it?.toList() ?: emptyList())
                        }
                    }
                }

                productsAdapter.updateData(productCategoryList) {
                    loadingIndicator.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }

            is ApiResult.Error -> // Handle error
            is ApiResult.Loading -> {} // Handle loading
        }
    }.collect()
}
```

Everything works fine but I can see that when products are added to the recyclerview, it blocks the UI for a very short time. The loading incdicator is lagging before products are displayed. (Only 13 Products)

How can I improve the implementation or is it even correct? Kotlin coroutines and flows provide so many possibilities which makes it sometimes very hard to find a good/correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect things you're doing that aren't harmful, but just make your code needlessly complicated:

- In your `getProducts` function, you don't need to wrap your flow inside a `flow` builder that you `emitAll` from. Drop the outer `flow { }` wrapper and the `.also { emitAll(it) }`.
- Never do the pattern `async { }.await()`. It's no different than simply calling the code inside that lambda directly. The compiler should be issuing you a warning when it detects you doing that.
- The `onEach { }.collect()` pattern can be shortened to `.collect { }`, or as I prefer, `collect()` can become `launchIn(scope)` and replace the outer `scope.launch` to reduce code nesting/indention.
- In `collectProducts()`, you create a scope with `coroutineScope` but never use it to run any child coroutines, so it is pointless.
- If you're using Flows from reputable libraries like Retrofit, Room, or Firebase, you don't need to use `flowOn` because they properly encapsulate any blocking work. Public flows should not block their downstream collectors. Likewise, you should not need `withContext` to call suspend functions from these libraries, because by convention, suspend functions should never block.

Incorrect and harmful things you're doing:

- In `loadCategoriesAndProducts()`, you are passing a SharedFlow to another function that collects it. This is creating a multiplication of the two flows that will get exponentially bigger as items arrive. This can be solved more simply as shown below. What you need to do instead is just combine the two flows.
- You should be using `repeatOnLifecycle` or `flowWithLifecycle` to avoid collecting while your Activity is off-screen,
  because that wastes resources.
- In your `categories?.forEach {`  block you are doing nested iteration unnecessarily.

If you want to use SharedFlow, which can avoid causing a new request to have to be remade, then you should put a function in your ViewModel that feeds the `networkID` into a MutableShateFlow that serves as a basis for another SharedFlow. You can declare your two parallel flows here privately and then combine them publicly.

```
// In ViewModel class:
private val _networkId = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
var networkId: String?
    get() = _networkId.value
    set(value) { _networkId.value = value }

private val products = _networkId.filterNotNull().distinctUntilChanged()
    .flatMapLatest { networkId ->
        request.getAll("network/${networkId}/products", null)
            .onStart { emit(ApiResult.Loading) }
            .catch { emit(ApiResult.Error(it.message.toString())) }
            .map { ApiResult.Success(it) }
    }

private val categories = _productsNetworkId.filterNotNull().distinctUntilChanged()
    .flatMapLatest { networkId ->
        request.getAll("network/${networkId}/categories", null) // I'm just guessing
            .onStart { emit(ApiResult.Loading) }
            .catch { emit(ApiResult.Error(it.message.toString())) }
            .map { ApiResult.Success(it) }
    }

val categoriesAndProducts: SharedFlow<ApiResult<List<Any>>> =
    products.combine(categories) { p, c ->
        when {
            p is ApiResult.Loading, c is ApiResult.Loading -> ApiResult.Loading
            p is ApiResult.Error -> p
            c is ApiResult.Error -> c
            else -> { // both are Success
                ApiResult.Success( 
                    c.data.orEmpty().flatMap { category ->
                        listOf(category) + p.data.orEmpty().filter { it.categoryId = category.id }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }.shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), replay = 1)
```

And then in your Activity:

```
private fun loadCategoriesAndProducts() {
    viewModel.networkId = networkId
    viewModel.categoriesAndProducts
        .onEach { 
            when(it) {
                is ApiResult.Loading -> {} // Handle loading
                is ApiResult.Error -> {} // Handle error

                is ApiResult.Success -> {
                    productsAdapter.updateData(productCategoryList) {
                        loadingIndicator.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .flowWithLifecycle(this, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
        .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
}
```

Other than that, the use of a `MutableList<Any>` is a code smell that creates a code maintainability problem.

Comment: Thank you! But I get a type missmatch when I try to emit new value like here `.onStart { emit(ApiResult.Loading) }`. Because `request.getAll(...)` returns a `Flow<List<...>>` I had to wrap it inside a flow builder to emit new values. Futher, I use Volley for network requests and have wrapped the response and error callbacks with `callbackFlow<List<T>>`